# Django Rest Framework Serializer Doesn't Display ALL Fields

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a problem where DRF isn't displaying all of my fields correctly for a model class / reference table (specifically the primary key).

My Model Class looks like this (very simple):

```
class UnitOfIssue(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('code',)                                                                                                                                                   

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} - {1}".format(self.code, self.description)
```

My Serializer Looks like this:

```
class UnitOfIssueSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """ 
    """
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
            read_only=True,
            view_name='unitofissue-detail',
            format='html',
            lookup_field='code')

    class Meta:
        model = UnitOfIssue
        fields = ('code', 'description', 'url')
        # fields = '__all__'
```

And I'm using a generic view:

```
class UnitOfIssueDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = UnitOfIssue.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UnitOfIssueSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    lookup_field = 'code'
```

In order for the `UnitOfIssue` primary key `code` to be displayed in the auto-generated UI, I have to define `fields = ('code', 'description', 'url')` in the serializer instead of `fields = '__all__'`.

I want to just be able to use the `'__all__'` syntax but I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Also, I'm using Django==1.11.13 and djangorestframework==3.8.2

Comment: any error msg??

Comment: @HemanthSP there was no error message, and I figured out what was wrong about 15 minutes after I posted the question (of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue plagued me for weeks, and yet it was such a simple error. I fixed it by changing the serializer base class from:

```
class UnitOfIssueSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
```

to:

```
class UnitOfIssueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```